# Connect to SQLite and cursor for different getting data functions

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have a SQLite database and I have multiple functions for multiple queries like below.
My question is about connecting to the database and cursor for each function. Is my code true and efficient? Is there another way to do it?

```
def get_all_data(database_addr: str):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(database_addr)
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute(
        """
        SELECT
        a.data
        FROM data_table a
        """
    )
    df = pd.DataFrame(c.fetchall(), columns=["data"])
    return df


def get_last_record(database_addr: str):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(database_addr)
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute(
        """
        SELECT * 
        FROM data_table 
        ORDER BY data_table.id DESC 
        LIMIT 1
        """
    )
    df = pd.DataFrame(c.fetchall(), columns=["id"])
    return df


def clear_local_data(last_record: int, database_addr: str):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(database_addr)
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute(
        """
        DELETE 
        FROM data_table a 
        WHERE a.id<=?
        """,
        (last_record,),
    )
    conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be connecting to the database for every time you query. If your program is a one off short running program, you can use a long lived connection, but if the connection dies then your program will stop working. If your program is a long running service, use [pooling](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/pooling.html) which will handle disconnects and other issues for you.

```py
conn = sqlite3.connect(database_addr)

def get_all_data(database_addr: str):
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute(
        """
        SELECT
        a.data
        FROM data_table a
        """
    )
    df = pd.DataFrame(c.fetchall(), columns=["data"])
    return df


def get_last_record(database_addr: str):
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute(
        """
        SELECT * 
        FROM data_table 
        ORDER BY data_table.id DESC 
        LIMIT 1
        """
    )
    df = pd.DataFrame(c.fetchall(), columns=["id"])
    return df
```

or

```py
import sqlalchemy.pool as pool
import sqlite3

mypool = pool.QueuePool(
    lambda: sqlite3.connect(database_addr),
    max_overflow=10,
    pool_size=5,
)

def get_all_data(database_addr: str):
    c = mypool.connect().cursor()
    c.execute(
        """
        SELECT
        a.data
        FROM data_table a
        """
    )
    df = pd.DataFrame(c.fetchall(), columns=["data"])
    return df


def get_last_record(database_addr: str):
    c = mypool.connect().cursor()
    c.execute(
        """
        SELECT * 
        FROM data_table 
        ORDER BY data_table.id DESC 
        LIMIT 1
        """
    )
    df = pd.DataFrame(c.fetchall(), columns=["id"])
    return df
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. which one is more efficient?

Comment: Long lived connection is unsafe since it might die at some point and then your program is dead, but if you're having just short runs it's usually enough. But if your program is a long running service, you should really use a pool which handles disconnections and such for you.

Comment: how it should be for a commit function, after inserting into the database? `mypool.commit()` or `mypool.connect().commit()` ?

Comment: In that case you need to put the connection in a variable `conn = mypool.connect()` and later `conn.commit()`. Sorry I missed the `DELETE` operation in my example.